# instances created in foreach loop are duplicates

Tags: php, oop

I've written code that reads data from a cURL source which then processes it to extract records of data.

Each record becomes an instance of an object with several variables set from the data. A function extracts all the data and returns an array of objects.

The problem is that all of the objects have the same value which is the last record to be read from the source data.

After some testing I realize this is a reference problem. Data is read from the source and then assigned to an object which is then added to the array. The same object is reused in a loop that cycles through all the records in the source. Whenever this object is updated all previous values in the objects in the array are also reset to the newest value as they continue to reference the object when it is updated.

How can I make all the values independent?

```
function get_object_array () {
        //reads raw data from cRUL source, returns array of objects

        //array to hold objects
        obj_arr = [];

        //raw data has been split into array called $record, one element for each object
        //loops through $record array
            foreach ($record as $rec) {
                //splits $rec into array of data called $data
                //creates new object, but problem here as this object
                //is being referenced by all values so last value
                //changes all previous objects in array
                $obj = new SaleItem();
                //populates object with record data array
                $obj->set_data($data);
                //add object to array
                $obj_arr [] = $obj;     
            }
        return $obj_arr;
    }
```

Update: Here is the function to set the data:

```
function set_data (array $arr) {
        global $order_num, $name, $price, $cprice, $cheapest, $category;
        try {
            $order_num = (int)$arr[0];
            $name = $arr[1];
            $price = (float)$arr[2];
            $cprice = (float)$arr[3];
            $cheapest = $this->$price <= $this->$cprice ? true : false;
            $category = $arr[5];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

Update: Full class code:

```
 class SaleItem {
    public $order_num = 12;
    public $name = "";
    public $price = 3.4;
    public $cprice = 5.6;
    public $cheapest = true;
    public $category = "No Category";

    function set_data (array $arr) {
        try {
            $this->order_num = (int)$arr[0];
            $this->name = $arr[1];
            $this->price = (float)$arr[2];
            $this->cprice = (float)$arr[3];
            $this->cheapest = $price <= $cprice ? true : false;
            $this->category = $arr[5];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
            return false;
        }   
    }

    function get_data () {
        echo $this->order_num . ' num<br/>';
        echo $this->name . ' name<br/>';
        echo $this->price . ' price<br/>';
        echo $this->cprice . ' cprice<br/>';
        echo $this->cheapest . ' cheapest<br/>';
        echo $this->category . ' category<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }

}//end SaleItem class
```

Comment: Should it not be `$obj->set_data($rec);`?

Comment: Where does `$data` come from???

Comment: $data is dervived from $rec after further processing. $rec is a string containing 6 values and $data is an array with these values split up and cleaned up from the string.

Comment: There is something else wrong in your code. And the way you process and set `$data` seems to be the culprit. Without seeing that, no way to debug your problem. Your code, as it is, [should work](https://repl.it/K5TL/0)

Comment: And your problems is not curl related at all. There is no curl code in your question.

Comment: You missed adding $this-> to `$price <= $cprice ? true : false;`. My answer below should be correct.

Comment: Yivi, yes the problem did not relate to the cURL operation so that detail was indeed irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using global variables instead of members. Remove

```
global $order_num, $name, $price, $cprice, $cheapest, $category;
```

From the function and preface each assignment with $this->

```
$this->order_num = (int)$arr[0];
        $this->name = $arr[1];
        $this->price = (float)$arr[2];
        $this->cprice = (float)$arr[3];
        $this->cheapest = $this->price <= $this->cprice;
        $this->category = $arr[5];
```

Comment: No, $rec requires further processing (not shown) to convert it into an array of values that the set_data function can use. I've tested the code and at this point the data is correct but it changes whenever $obj is updated with newer data making all previous values also become the same. Thanks.

Comment: We will need to see SaleItem::set_data and any sub functions then. If $data is correct at the call to set_data the issue lies in the object's assignment. The setting of $data would also be useful, even if it is a faked/commented piece of code for reference.

Comment: Edited based on your new information. You are assigning global vars which are the same in every instance instead of member specific variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now errors say that the variables have not been defined.

Comment: These variables need to be defined in your class somewhere as member variables. Without a full class definition and all code involded I am forced to make assumptions about the completeness of your code.

Comment: These are just wild guesses without more information.

Comment: William Wilson: Class vars have always been present.

Comment: Is set_data really defined inside the class {}. Is the undefined vars coming from this function? Can you post the full class, not a snippet? Did you get all vars, including right side of this: `$this->cheapest = $this->price <= $this->cprice;`

Comment: Thanks again. Fixed that but still getting undefined variable error for line $this->order_num ....

Comment: You have extra $ in your code. Read mine carefully: `$this->order_num` only 1 $ on $this.

Comment: Thank you very much, now working. It was indeed the vars being set as class vars that were persisting over all instances. Using $this->var_name solved the issue after I removed my superfluous $ errors.